# Understanding Kramers-Kronig relations

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm a bit confused on how to calculate the Kramer-Kronig relations using the principal values, so I was hoping if someone could explain me how to proceed.

As you know, for a function $\chi(\omega)=\chi_1(\omega)+i\chi_2(\omega)$, the Kramer-Kronig relations are given by:

$$\chi_1(\omega)=\frac{1}{\pi}P\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d\Omega\frac{\chi_2(\Omega)}{\Omega-\omega}$$

$$\chi_2(\omega)=-\frac{1}{\pi}P\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d\Omega\frac{\chi_1(\Omega)}{\Omega-\omega}$$

where the principal value for a singularity at $\eta$ can be calculated as,

$$P\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx f(x)=\lim_{c\rightarrow 0^+}\left[ \int_{-\infty}^{\eta-c/2}dx f(x)+\int_{\eta+c/2}^{\infty}dx f(x)\right ]$$

However, just following from this definition I'm not able to make any calculation for the cases I've tested so far, so I would like to understand how is this done (all the books I've reviewed so far only include theory).

For example, take the most simple case for real part of a susceptibility function $\chi_1(\omega)=\omega_p^2/\omega^2$. If I insert it into the second equation and I try calculating the corresponding real part,

$$\chi_2(\omega)=\frac{\omega_p^2}{\pi}P\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d\Omega\frac{1}{\Omega^2(\Omega-\omega)}$$

Which gives me $\chi_2(\omega)=-\infty (sgn(\omega))$ upon calculation of the integrals for both singularities at $\Omega=0$ and $\Omega=\omega$. This is strange, as it doesn't make sense that an imaginary part of a real quantity is infinite.

Therefore, tried using an alternative definition found in the French version of Wikipedia,

$$\chi_2(\omega)=-\frac{2\omega}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}d\Omega\frac{\chi_2(\Omega)}{\Omega^2-\omega^2}$$

which doesn't have the principal value for some reason. If I assume symmetry and I take the limit from zero to infinity, I can use the residu theorem to calculate that integral, I actually get $\chi_2(\omega)=-2i\omega_p^2/\omega^2$. It also doesn't make too much sense, since I'm now getting an imaginary number which will cancel with the $i$ of the imaginary part ($i\chi_2(\omega)$).

Therefore, I know I'm doing something wrong or lacking some mathematical tool to do the correct computations.

Comment: Hint: according to Wikipedia the functions Re and Im must be meromorphic with poles only in the lower Omega plane. https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kramers-Kronig-Beziehungen

Comment: That's true, but how can you evaluate them explicitly?

Comment: Your example does not obey the conditions.Take the real part of a function which has a pole in the lower plane. For example try $\Re(\frac{1}{\Omega+i}) = \frac{\Omega}{\Omega^2 +1 }$.

Comment: But the example also has poles, at least one in the origin. Couldn't if be used?

Comment: Which example do you mean? Ä